# Python list "commander" (modify a list with user commands)

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

I made a program that can modify a list using commands that the user enters.

The commands that are supported are (used from actual program):

- `/add [value1] [value2] [valueN]...` - Add a value to the list
- `/rvalue [value]` - Removes a value from the list
- `/rindex [index]` - Removes the value at the specified index from the list
- `/print` - Prints the list
- `/help` - Lists every available command

Here is the code:

```
#Program to modify lists

value_list = []

def cmd_help():
    print("/add [value1] [value2] [valueN]... - Add a value to the list")
    print("/rvalue [value] - Removes a value from the list")
    print("/rindex [index] - Removes the value at the specified index from the list")
    print("/print - Prints the list")
    print("/help - Lists every available command")

def get_command_params():
    commands = {
        "/add": lambda *value : value_list.extend(list(value)),
        "/rvalue": lambda value : value_list.remove(value),
        "/rindex": lambda value : value_list.pop(int(value)),
        "/print": lambda : print(value_list),
        "/help": cmd_help
    }

    while True:
        input_cmd = input("Enter a command: ")

        #Separate arguments
        command = ""
        current_args_index = -1
        args = []
        last_char = ""

        for char in input_cmd:
            #Update separator
            if char == "/" or char == " ":
                last_char = char

            if last_char == "/":
                command += char
            elif last_char == "append":
                args[current_args_index] += char
            elif last_char == " ":
                args.append("")
                #To append individual characters to same index
                last_char = "append"
                ++current_args_index

        cmd = commands.get(command)
        if cmd == None:
            print("Invalid command!")
            continue

        return cmd, args

def main():
    cmd_help()

    #Wait for command
    while True:
        command, args = get_command_params()

        #Execute command with arguments
        try:
            command(*args)

            #Don't print success if command is print/help
            if args != []:
                print("Success!")
        except IndexError:
            print("Index out of range!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Element not found!")
        except TypeError:
            print("Invalid arguments! Type /help for help")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> value_list = []
> ```

Global variables are almost never necessary.  If you are tempted to use a global, you have two choices:

1. Give the variable as an argument and reassign it to what the function returns (or just give it if the function mutates it).
2. Define a class and use instance attributes.

In this case, `value_list` is used by far too many things and with `lambda` functions and everything.  Therefore, I would suggest that you define a `Commands` class.

> ```
> "/add": lambda *value : value_list.extend(list(value))
> ```

You don't need to convert `value` to a list.  That is just unnecessary processing time.  A list can be extended by a list, a tuple, a string, a generator, ... whatever iterable you want.

> ```
> "/rindex": lambda value : value_list.pop(int(value)),
> ```

I wouldn't convert it to an integer within a `lambda` function.  I would create a whole function that uses a `try` block in case the user doesn't type a valid number.  That is also helpful if the user does type a number, but types a number that is too big or too small.

> ```
> elif last_char == "append"
> ...
>     last_char = "append"
> ```

Don't use magic numbers (or magic values).  You should define a constant called `APPEND` that can really be assigned to any object except a single-character string.

> ```
> ++current_args_index
> ```

Python doesn't use `++`.  If `x` is `4`, then `+x` is `4` and `++x` is still `4`.  If `x` is `-4`, then `+x` is `-4` and `++x` is still `-4`.  In other words, it does absolutely nothing.  Python isn't like C where that increments `current_args_index`.  If you want to increment it, do `current_args_index += 1`

> ```
> cmd = ...
> if cmd == None:
>     ...
> ```

I have two problems.  First, if you treat `None` as a special case, you can simply use a `try` block.  Second, you should say `is None`, not `== None` because a class could define its `__eq__` method to say that any instance is equal to `None`, but only `None` really `is None`.

Your `main()` function and how you use it looks terrific!  You take care of each error separately, and you don't call `main()` unless your file is being run as a program.  Keep it up!